How to create a non-generic TypeAlias of Callable in python
I have successfully (such that mypy doesn't complain) written type hints for decorators with parameters that decorate class methods in python 3.11.9:
import functools
from typing import Callable, TypeVar


MyClassType = TypeVar("MyClassType", bound=object)
T = TypeVar("T")


def reader(uri: str) -> Callable[[Callable[[MyClassType], T]], Callable[[MyClassType], T]]:
    def decorator(fun: Callable[[MyClassType], T]) -> Callable[[MyClassType], T]:
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(subsys: MyClassType) -> T:
            return fun(subsys)
        wrapper.uri = uri
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def writer(uri: str) -> Callable[[Callable[[MyClassType, T], None]], Callable[[MyClassType, T], None]]:
    def decorator(fun: Callable[[MyClassType, T], None]) -> Callable[[MyClassType, T], None]:
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(subsys: MyClassType, value: T) -> None:
            fun(subsys, value)
        wrapper.uri = uri
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class MyClass:
    @reader("test")
    def _my_reader(self) -> int:
        return 1

    @writer("test")
    def _my_writer(self, val: float) -> None:
        print(val)

Now I would like to shorten the decorators' return typehints like so:
import functools
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, TypeAlias


MyClassType = TypeVar("MyClassType", bound=object)
T = TypeVar("T")

ReaderMethod: TypeAlias = Callable[[MyClassType], T]
WriterMethod: TypeAlias = Callable[[MyClassType, T], None]

# ReaderMethod = TypeVar("ReaderMethod", bound=Callable[[MyClassType], T])
# WriterMethod = TypeVar("WriterMethod", bound=Callable[[MyClassType, T], None])


def reader(uri: str) -> Callable[[ReaderMethod], ReaderMethod]:
    def decorator(fun: ReaderMethod) -> ReaderMethod:
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(subsys: MyClassType) -> T:
            return fun(subsys)
        wrapper.uri = uri
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def writer(uri: str) -> Callable[[WriterMethod], WriterMethod]:
    def decorator(fun: WriterMethod) -> WriterMethod:
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(subsys: MyClassType, value: T) -> None:
            fun(subsys, value)
        wrapper.uri = uri
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class MyClass:
    @reader("test")
    def _my_reader(self) -> int:
        return 1

    @writer("test")
    def _my_writer(self, val: float) -> None:
        print(val)

Neither the uncommented nor commented version of ReaderMethod/WriterMethod work, mypy complains about line 18, for example "A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar", among other (type hint) problems. What am I doing wrong? How can I improve my type hints such that I have these aliases ReaderMethod/WriterMethod and mypy is happy?
Edit: In line 15, mypy complains 'Missing type parameters for generic type "ReaderMethod"', hence the title of the question.

Just because you've defined a generic alias doesn't mean you can stop using the type variables. MyClassType and T aren't "implicit" in the use of ReaderMethod, passing silently to the definition of wrapper.
You might want even one more alias, to define the "transformer" type.
type Transformer[F] = Callable[[F], F]

def reader(uri: str)[A, RV] -> Transformer[ReaderMethod[A, RV]]:
    def decorator(fun: ReaderMethod[[A], RV]) -> ReaderMethod[[A], RV]:
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(subsys: A) -> RV:
            return fun(subsys)
        wrapper.uri = uri
        return wrapper
    return decorator

